# Split a string on spaces but not if space is inside quotes(quoted part can be like xxx"x x x"xxx

Tags: java, regex, split

*Input*

```
abc hello" I am batman"xoxo bat man
```

*Output*

- abc
- hello I am batmanxoxo (remove the quotes)
- bat
- man

I am using `\"(.*?)\"` to grab the stuff inside quotes but can't grab the remaining non-whitespace part.

Comment: Try matching with [`[^\s"]+(?:"[^"]+"[^\s"]*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/lR35aO/1) or [`(?:"[^"]+"|[^\s"])+`](https://regex101.com/r/lR35aO/2) and add found items to the resulting list while removing `"` with a mere `.replace("\"", "")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using a mathing pattern, and then remove the `"` :

- pattern `(?:"[^"]*"|\S)+` :  non-capturing group that will

  - if find a `"` will wait (take all non-quote char `[^"]`) the second `"` to look for space
  - if find a letter, take all non-space char (\S)
- replace `"` but empty string

---

```
String str = "abc hello\" I am batman\"xoxo bat man";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:\"[^\"]*\"|\\S)+").matcher(str);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find())
    res.add(m.group().replaceAll("\"", ""));

System.out.println(res);       //[abc, hello I am batmanxoxo, bat, man]
```

Comment: @Sneh You're welcome, you maybe think about voteup/accept, this is how a forum work, and this is how it'll help future askers to look around here

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string using the ".
Like

```
String s= "abc hello\" I am batman\"xoxo bat man";
String[] splittedString = s.split("\"");
```

splittedString will be "abc hello", " I am batman", "xoxo bat man".
And use only the odd index from splittedString.

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < splittedString.lengt; i++){
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    result.addAll(Arrays.asList(splittedString[i].split(" ")));
  } else {
    result.add(splittedString[i]);
  }
}
```